# Inserting a long text in H2 Database from an SQL script

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, h2

I'm trying to run a sql script using H2's runscript.

One of the table contains a longtext type which stores an xml document (from an SAP database)

So the Insert statement contains the long text of the XML (about 200 lines of XML), which is rather ugly but still expected to work.

H2 crashes with an ArrayOutOfBoundException during SQL parsing.

- Is there alimit on the length it will accept for a insert statement ?
- In the nsert I'm delimiting the value(xml) using ticks (as used in mysql) ... figures this would minimize escaping.  could that be part of the issue (works for other short fields)

I would prefer using the plain runscript H2 tool here rather than make a Java program although I see it would be cleaner (could use the steam methods)

Any insight ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never mind

Got it working by using the proper delimiters (" for column names and ' for values) and escaping quotes in values properly (doubling it)