# H2 db Inserting data with quotes throw exception

Tags: mysql, h2

I am trying replace my normal msqldb  with a inmemory h2 database ( mysql mode) for unit test. Please see the description of the table

```
'CREATE TABLE `dummyTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value1` longtext,
`value2` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ) ENGI

NE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Then I try to insert **longtext** field with **‘** in it. In **mysql**, I escaped it with \ and the insert statement worked fine but in **h2 db** its throws following exception.

**insert  into dummyTable values (6,'ad\'s', 'def')**

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "insert  into dummyTable values (6,'ad's','df[*]')"; SQL statement:
insert  into dummyTable values (6,'ad's','df') [42000-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:229)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:989)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.checkRunOver(Parser.java:5129)
```

I tried another insert statement

**insert  into dummyTable values (6,"ad\'s","df")**

But it also failed with following exception

```
 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "ad's" not found; SQL statement:
    insert  into dummyTable values (6,"ad's","df") [42122-199]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451

)
```

Could some one please how to do that in h2 db

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doubling the single quotes.

For eg: 
insert into dummyTable values (6,'ad''s', 'def')

This post [Inserting a long text in H2 Database from an SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600335/inserting-a-long-text-in-h2-database-from-an-sql-script/4601010) helped

Comment: Some problem if you export from a database and the inputs are define with ` (e.g: `data`). This one should also be replaced with '